# Restore hotcopy of svn repo

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I have a hotcopy of an svn repo and now I want to restore that hotcopy on another server, whats the best way of doing that? The OS of the two servers are different but the svn version is same,  Note that I made a hotcopy instead of an svn dump because because the total repo size is 20gb which means that the svn dump would be several times bigger and I have limited space. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfully able to migrate the repository from one server to another server and here is how I did it:-

- Made a hotcopy of the repository, I didnt do `svn dump` because my repo was around 20gb so the estimated dump size was above 100gb and I was tight on space.
- Installed Visual SVN Server on the server I wanted my repo to be on.
- From the SVN Server interface I selected `import existing repository` and gave the path to my hotcopy.

Note that the OS version of both the servers was different and I was worried that it might create an issue but I didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Repository hotcopy is a fully functional repository ready to be exposed to endusers via Apache HTTP Server or `svnserve`. Read the documentation about hotcopy at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup.

Comment: I have been through the documentation, it has information about creating a hotcopy but I dont see anything useful about restoring a hotcopy

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul You just need to copy the repository to your repositories root directory. I mean the directory where you store the repositories.

Comment: I have created a hotcopy of my repositories, now I am trying to restoring that hotcopy on a different server. How do I do that?